# Down casting Object array to array of type parameter

Tags: java, arrays, generics

How is the statement in the GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava constructor working? Could some1 please explain ?

```
public class GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava<I> {


    private I[] i;


    public GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava(int n)
    {
        i = (I[]) new Object[n];//works and prints out "Created". How?
        System.out.println("Created");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava<String>(2);

        String[] strs = (String[])  new Object[2]; // throws ClassCastException. When this statement doesn't work, how is the "(I[]) new Object[n]" statement working? 

    }

}
```

Comment: related: [How to: generic array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i = (I[]) new Object[n];
```

It is not entirely clear what you *think* the above does, but one thing it most definitely doesn't do is create an array of `I`. The only part responsible for choosing the type of the array comes after the `new` keyword: It's an array of `Object`s, unsafely cast to `I[]`.

The compiler must allow the line to compile because it doesn't know anything about the type `I`: it could as well be `Object`, so the line is legal.

Also note that the [*erased*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) type of `I[]` is `Object[]`: the actual type (in the bytecode) of the `i` variable is `Object[]`. Therefore the assignment succeeds at runtime no matter what type the instance is parameterized with.

A `ClassCastException` will only be thrown if the array is assigned back to a *reifiable* type. For example:

```
GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava o =
        new GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava<String>(2);

String[] strs = o.i; // ClassCastException thrown here
```

During the type erasure process, the compiler inserts the cast to `String[]` in the line assigning `strs`. This demonstrates the need to keep `i` from "leaking" outside the class that is using it.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is going on, simply consider the same code after type erasure (just remove type parameters and insert casts if necessary):

```
public class GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava {


    private Object[] i;


    public GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava(int n)
    {
        i = (Object[]) new Object[n];//works and prints out "Created". How?
        System.out.println("Created");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GenericArrayCreationIsDisallowedInJava(2);

        String[] strs = (String[])  new Object[2]; // throws ClassCastException. When this statement doesn't work, how is the "(I[]) new Object[n]" statement working? 

    }

}
```